# Cayley table for a group of order 5

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I know how to work the cayley table up to a group of order 4. I'm having difficulty in doing one with order 5

Comment: What is giving you problems? I assume you have not learned Lagrange's theorem yet?

Answer (score 2):

Up to isomorphism, there is only one group of order $5$ (since $5$ is prime), which is a cyclic group.  The process of writing its Cayley table should be virtually the same as used for writing the Cayley table of order $3$.

How you write the table depends on which isomorphism class representative you prefer.  If we use $\langle g | g^5=1 \rangle$, then it's a matter of filling in the table:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
    & 1 & g & g^2 & g^3 & g^4 \\
\hline
1   & \\
g   & \\
g^2 & \\
g^3 & & & & & g^2\\
g^4 & \\
\end{array}
$$

In cell $(g^i,g^j)$ we write $$g^i g^j=g^{i+j}=g^{i+j \text{ mod } 5}.$$  As an example, I filled in the cell $(g^3,g^4)$ with $$g^3g^4=g^7=g^2.$$

Comment: Is there a convention in use regarding isomorphism class representative selection?